# Using a toggle button inside side menu ionic framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have created a sideMenu and one of the item inside it has a text on left, and a toggle (checkbox) on the right. Menu item is linked to a view, which has a list of items. Toggle is like a button, which allow user to clear the list, without having to go inside the view.

Earlier I had 'menu-close' attribute added to the menu item, so every time I click the toggle, it would change the value and close the side menu.

Now the issue is, after removing the 'menu-close' I can click on the toggle and menu stays open, but the menu-item link is not working. I have tried setting ng-click and href. If I set href, the item navigates to new view even if I click on toggle.

```
<ion-item class="item-toggle" ng-click="openNotifications()">
     <i class="icon ion-android-notifications-none"></i>
     Notifications
     <label class="toggle toggle-assertive">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="alert('notification on')">
          <div class="track">
              <div class="handle"></div>
          </div>
     </label>
</ion-item>
```

How can make sure that if I click on toggle it changes, and when I click on item it navigates to view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to add `$event.stopPropagation()` to the outer click event, click events propagate and bubble so that is why both are firing.

try this:

```
<ion-item class="item-toggle" ng-click="openNotifications()">
     <i class="icon ion-android-notifications-none"></i>
     Notifications
     <label class="toggle toggle-assertive">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="alert('notification on');$event.stopPropagation()">
          <div class="track">
              <div class="handle"></div>
          </div>
     </label>
</ion-item>
```

FIXED IT:

so you need the stop prorogation, you also need to add this to the css to make the toggle item clickable:

```
.item-toggle{
  pointer-events:initial !important;
}
```

here is a ionic playground to show it working!
http://play.ionic.io/app/d9920eee107d

Comment: I tired it, added stopPropagation to item and then to checkbox, but its same. Only toggle field/checkbox is working, nothing happens when I click on item.

Comment: Perfect! It's indeed working now. Can you explain what does pointer-events does?

Comment: The CSS property pointer-events allows authors to control under what circumstances (if any) a particular graphic element can become the target of mouse events. so in ionic the item toggle class turns off pointer events to the item by default to everything but the toggle switch.

Answer (score 0):

You could place the toogle inside a normal list-item, to prevent the toogle-item behavior.

```
<ion-item ng-click="show('click')">
    Item     
    <label class="toggle">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="state" ng-change="show(state)">
        <div class="track">
            <div class="handle"></div>
        </div>
    </label>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: I have tried it earlier and yet again. But, this doesn't work as expected. It fires both "show('click')" and show(state), when I click on toggle button.